# jQuery disable a div, when click anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hidden-field

[image]

here is my comment form's textarea with my hidden inputs.

```
$('#c_text').click(function() {
    if ($('#hidden_part').attr('class') == 'closed') {
        $('#hidden_part').css('display','block');
        $('#hidden_part').removeClass('closed');
    } else {
        $('#hidden_part').css('display','none');
        $('#hidden_part').addClass('closed');
    };
});
```

when i click, textarea hidden input apper well, but, 
how can i hide this part name called `#hidden_part`
anywhere else on page ?

Comment: `jQuery disable a div` Can you please explain what this exactly means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hide the div content when clicking on the document and use **event.stopPropagation();** method when clicking on the textarea so that the div content will be displayed,

Here is the example...

**HTML Code**

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="hidden_part">
     <a href="google.com">Google</a>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse congue ipsum quam, nec blandit sapien eleifend eget. Cras cursus ullamcorper risus nec rutrum. Praesent lobortis nibh turpis. Curabitur eleifend leo ultricies efficitur dignissim. Aliquam eget dapibus nisi. Fusce dictum laoreet enim, nec blandit arcu feugiat sagittis. Mauris non dolor nec dui luctus ornare. Vestibulum pulvinar metus diam, eu vulputate leo suscipit ut. Donec eget consequat sem, et finibus lorem.</p>    
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#hidden_part").hide();
});

$('textarea').click(function(event){
    $("#hidden_part").show();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dc3Lngw3/

Comment: its ok but could you try fill some input in the hidden_pat id. 

http://jsfiddle.net/fatihtoprak/zm20jvj5/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L3gh6heg/ ?

```html
<textarea id="c_text">Textarea</textarea>

<div id="hidden_part">Hidden Part</div>
```

```js
$("#c_text").focusin(function () {
    $("#hidden_part").show();
});

$("#c_text").focusout(function () {
    $("#hidden_part").hide();
});
```

`focusin` detects when an element gains focus and `focusout` detects when an element loses focus.

jQuery also allows you to call `show` and `hide` on elements which is probably easier to use than manually setting the css.

Comment: that is ok but there is some input also, hidden_part. i should use this inputs also when i add a comment.

Comment: @FatihToprak I don't understand, could you explain further?

Comment: tnahks about the replay @Divakar Gujjala 's replay is the sulation.

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to hide and show bloc when your textarea is focus. Use a focusins/focusout event.

```
$('#c_text').focusin(function() {
   $('#hidden_part').css('display','block');      
}).focusout( function() {
   $('#hidden_part').css('display','none');
});
```

Avantage is simple, if you select your field with tab navigation, events are called.

Comment: that is ok but there is some input also, hidden_part. i should use this inputs also when i add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Fatih,

Can you try this

```
$("#c_text").click(function(ev){
    if($('#hidden_part').css("display") == "none"){
        $('#hidden_part').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('#hidden_part').slideUp();
    }
    ev.stopPropagation();

    $(document).click(function() {
             $("#hidden_part").slideUp();

    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serkanalgur/xq48kcff/2/)

Comment: thanks but please try write something in the hidden_part input that what i confused again.

http://jsfiddle.net/fatihtoprak/zm20jvj5/

Comment: Oh, you extend your question :) Is there any other extened option in form? Like ajax login or else, if i update code you cant close #hidden_part without an action

Comment: You can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serkanalgur/zm20jvj5/1/) i added an 'Kapat' button for close hidden_part

Comment: tnahks about fast replay @Serkan Divakar Gujjala 's replay is the sulation.